# How to sort by name descending in lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects that are sorted in descending order by date:

```
_.sortBy
  (persons.entities.alerts,
  dateObj => new Date(dateObj.createdDateTime)
).reverse()
```

This is the array:

```
let persons={
  "entities": {
    "applicants": [
      {
        "lastName": "Agamemnon",
        "isPrimaryApplicant": true,
        "id": "16671520038"
      },
      {
        "lastName": "Purdy",
        "isPrimaryApplicant": false,
        "id": "16671520039"
      },
      {
        "lastName": "Brekky",
        "isPrimaryApplicant": true,
        "id": "16671520040"
      },
      {
        "lastName": "Tabouli",
        "isPrimaryApplicant": true,
        "id": "16671520041"
      }
    ],
    "alerts": [
      {
        "createdDateTime": "2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "applicants": ["16671520038", "16671520039"],
        "id": "05025fea-ec37-4767-a868-a646597365d0"
      },
      {
        "createdDateTime": "2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "applicants": ["16671520040"],
        "id": "19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc83869"
      },
      {
        "createdDateTime": "2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "applicants": ["16671520041"],
        "id": "c5385595-2104-409d-a676-c1b57346f63e"
      }
    ]
  }

}
```

The sort returns the correct order by date desc.  In this sample the dates are the same. Only in this case i want to sort by (applicants) lastName where isPrimaryApplicant=true? Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/bertie2017/pen/QYwrGd?editors=0002)

Comment: Note that your `createdDateTime` properties are all identical...

Comment: Yes, only when the dates are the same i want to sort by name. If the dates are different just by date.

Comment: What name does an alert have? it looks like an alert can have multiple applicants and the applicants array has objects with name property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would have loved to use lodash for this but the documentation does not reflect reality. The second argument to _.sortBy is an array in documentation but doesn't work if I pass an array of functions.

You can add names to your alerts and while your at it add a sortDate to use for sorting:

```js
const persons={"entities":{"applicants":[{"lastName":"Agamemnon","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520038"},{"lastName":"Purdy","isPrimaryApplicant":false,"id":"16671520039"},{"lastName":"Brekky","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520040"},{"lastName":"Tabouli","isPrimaryApplicant":true,"id":"16671520041"}],"alerts":[{"createdDateTime":"2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z","applicants":["16671520038","16671520039"],"id":"05025fea-ec37-4767-a868-a646597365d0"},{"createdDateTime":"2018-06-14T00:00:00.000Z","applicants":["16671520041"],"id":"19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc83869"},{"createdDateTime":"2019-06-14T00:00:00.000Z","applicants":["16671520040"],"id":"c5385595-2104-409d-a676-c1b57346f63e"}]}}

const applicantsById = persons.entities.applicants.reduce(
    (result, applicant) => result.set(applicant.id, applicant),
    new Map(),
);
const alertsWithName = persons.entities.alerts.map((alert) => ({
    ...alert,
    sortDate:new Date(alert.createdDateTime).getTime(),
    name: (alert.applicants
        .map((id) => applicantsById.get(id))
        .filter((x) => x) //remove empty
        .find((applicant)=>applicant.isPrimaryApplicant)||{lastName:''}).lastName
}));

//according to not correct lodash documentation here:
//https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortBy
//we should be able to do this:
// console.log(
//   _.sortBy(alertsWithName, [
//     (alert) => new Date(alert.createdDateTime),
//     (alert) => alert.name,
//   ])
// )
//however that's not going to work so can try array sort method

console.log(
  alertsWithName.sort(
    (a,b)=>b.sortDate-a.sortDate || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dude I tried your code with just changing the Tabouli date to today. It should appear on top then because I want to sort by date in descending order

Comment: @bierhier Newest date comes first, changed the code to `b.sortDate-a.sortDate` that should fix it.

Comment: Did you also take into consideration  the isPrimaryApplicant=true?

Comment: @bierhier will an action with more than one applicants be guaranteed to have only one applicant where isPrimaryApplicant is true? In that case names can be name and instead of an array of strings it can be one string.

Comment: Yes just get the applicant with isPrimaryApplicant=true

Comment: @bierhier Modified the answer, now taking the first applicant from an action that has isPrimaryApplicant to true. So names has changed to name and is a string instead of an array of strings.

Comment: You nailed it :)

Answer (score 12):

**You want lodash's [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy), which allows sort directions.**

You can attach `asc` or `desc` to each sort property you use.

This should get you the ordering you're looking for:

`_.orderBy(persons.entities.applicants, ['lastName'], ['desc'])`

Answer (score 2):

Loadash sortBy doesn't provide option for comparator function(though there are other ways to achieve it)

You can use array sort method to achieve this:

```
persons.entities.alerts.sort(function(a1, a2) { 
    if(a1.createdDateTime === a2.createdDateTime) {
        let applicant1 = persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id === a1.applicants[0]);
        let applicant2 = persons.entities.applicants.find(a => a.id === a2.applicants[0]);
        if (!applicant1.isPrimaryApplicant || applicant1.lastName < applicant2.lastName) {
           return -1;
       }
       return 1;

    } else {
        let d1 = new Date(a1.createdDateTime);
        let d2 = new Date(a2.createdDateTime);
        return d2 - d1;
    }
})
```

Comment: Is applicant1 in the else section undefined?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I actually ran this code and if I change the date to today for applicant "16671520041" ie Tabouli then it is not top of the list. Should be descending by date.

Comment: Can you please try with the latest one.

Comment: Did you also take into consideration  the isPrimaryApplicant=true?

Comment: Updated to consider now.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort first then reverse

```
  //====SORT====
  sortArray(list: any[], field: string): any[] {
    return list = _.sortBy(list.sort(), field).reverse()
  }

//--
    this.yourList = this.sortArray(this.yourList , 'createdDateTime')
//--
```